# How properly calculate and place an image on top of another image when they're both scaled - cross browser?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-website

I have a base image with items on it. If the user disables one of the items, it should then show as disabled. To handle this, I use a second image of the item disabled (a png) and place that in the correct location above the background image.

When there's no scaling, this works perfectly across all browsers.

When there's scaling (for example, in a mobile browser when the image is 40% of the original size) this **only works in Firefox**. Firefox always places the image in the correct spot, covering the item underneath.

The other browsers (Chrome on Android, Safari iOS), are always off by 1-2 pixels depending on the scaling level. So you can see a little bit of the item below.

How can I do this so it works cross-browser?

```
var heightRatio = bgOffsetHeight / originalHeight;
var widthRatio = bgOffsetWidth / originalWidth;

//Place the disabled items
for ( var i = 0; i < disableds.length; i++ )
{
    var disabled = disableds[ i ];

    /**
     * I also tried with "parseInt", but it still doesn't work.
     * 
     * originalLeft/Top/Width/Height are the values saved in 
     * JavaScript when the page is first loaded before everything
     * is scaled.
     */
    disabled.style.left = ( widthRatio * disabled.originalLeft ) + "px";
    disabled.style.top = ( heightRatio * disabled.originalTop ) + "px";
    disabled.style.width = ( widthRatio * disabled.originalWidth ) + "px";
    disabled.style.height = ( heightRatio * disabled.originalHeight ) + "px";

    //Make visible
    disabled.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: This could be due to rounding errors which FF handles better in many cases, but not sure without seeing a complete example. But maybe you can replace the BG image itself instead trying to place something on the top?

Comment: @frontend_dev I think that's probably the case. Replacing the BG image could work but with the number of items (20), I'd need to do a version for every combination which is 20 factorial I believe.

Comment: modify the opacity? fading something out is a common mechanism for indicating inaccessibility -change the cursor/kill and disable any actions resulting from user interaction with the object.

Comment: Or, you could try to work with percentages instead of pixel values, but you might end up with the same problem. This is an age old problem that also occurs with percentage based collumns etc. FF just handles this cases better.

Comment: @MatiuCarr That doesn't work. The back one is showing because the top image is being placed either 1 pixel too far right or too far down, etc.

Comment: I meant -do not place something on top, just fade the original.

Comment: @MatiuCarr How? The original has all the items on it in enabled colors.

Comment: @frontend_dev I found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Does your background use white or another solid color? Then you could try this: place an empty div over the bg portion and then apply `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)` for example. This should give you the same effect, plus it would save a whole lot of additional images. But only works if "the bg of your bg" is a solid color.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work because the background image has a lot of stuff on it. Not just the items, but lines and other images going around them

Comment: OK, so you really make it tough ;) Could be that it wont ever work 100% then, this pesky rounding problems can be pretty hard to come by.

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises in WebKit only, where separately calculating the width and height ratio gives the browser an inability to properly size and place images. If I change my code to only use the width ratio, then everything places correctly across all browsers:

```
//We no longer use height ratio for the height/top calculations
//var heightRatio = bgOffsetHeight / originalHeight;
var widthRatio = bgOffsetWidth / originalWidth;

//Place the disabled items
for ( var i = 0; i < disableds.length; i++ )
{
    var disabled = disableds[ i ];

    /**
     * I also tried with "parseInt", but it still doesn't work.
     * 
     * originalLeft/Top/Width/Height are the values saved in 
     * JavaScript when the page is first loaded before everything
     * is scaled.
     */
    disabled.style.left = ( widthRatio * disabled.originalLeft ) + "px";
    disabled.style.top = ( widthRatio * disabled.originalTop ) + "px";
    disabled.style.width = ( widthRatio * disabled.originalWidth ) + "px";
    disabled.style.height = ( widthRatio * disabled.originalHeight ) + "px";

    //Make visible
    disabled.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```